# Self cookies in cross-domain iframe not working

Tags: iframe, cookies, cross-domain

I've got the situation below:

```
+-------------------------+
| not-my-website.com      |
|   +--------------------+|
|   | my-website.local   ||
|   |                    ||
|   |(Can't read or write||
|   |its own cookies)    ||
|   |                    ||
|   +--------------------+|
+---+---------------------+
```

My problem is that my-website.local is not able to write or read its own cookies (my-website.local cookies).

Most surprising is that google chrome developer console displays the cookies that was existing before (from an another tab where my-website.local in full page), but it does not send cookies with the request to load the iframe content.

Is there a way to get this working ?

Thank you

Comment: In fact I was using Chromium-browser.
This is working as it should in Google-chrome and Firefox.

However, this question remains pending!

Comment: same here. but issue just started a few days ago. it still worked last week. I'll probably submit a bug report.

Comment: Submitted a bug report https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377494. Feel free to comment on the issue if you think I missed any details.